# Computing Fourier Series of $f(x) = x(\pi-x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Consider the $2\pi$-periodic odd function defined on $[0,\pi]$ by $f(x) = x(\pi - x)$ Show that the fourier series of $f$ can be written as $f(x) = \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n:odd \geq 1} \frac{sin(nx)}{n^3}$

First I computed $a_0$ to be: $$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi x(\pi - x)dx = \frac{\pi^3}{6}$$

Then since $f$ is odd we get a sine series with coefficients $$b_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi x(\pi-x)sin(nx)dx = -\dfrac{2\left(\left(2nx-{\pi}n\right)\sin\left(nx\right)+\left(-n^2x^2+{\pi}n^2x+2\right)\cos\left(nx\right)\right)}{{\pi}n^3}_0^\pi$$ $$= -\frac{4}{\pi n^3}$$ where $n$ is odd. I checked the integral with a calculator to make sure it is correct, but it obviously gives us the wrong expression for the fourier series. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $a_0$ is $0$. This is true for any odd function.

Comment: You probably forgot a minus sign when evaluating the integral, it should be $\frac{4}{\pi n^3}$. Also note that you have to multiply it by $2$ since we only integrate it over $0$ to $\pi$ instead of from $-\pi$ to $\pi$

Comment: @Raffaele How come there is no $a_0$ if $f$ is not odd?

Comment: @leoli1 so it should be $$b_n = \frac{4}{\pi} \int_0^\pi x(\pi-x)sin(nx)dx$$ ?

Comment: Yes. @Raffaele The formula $f(x)=x(\pi-x)$ is by definition only valid for $x\in[0,\pi]$. The function $f$ is on $[-\pi,\pi]$ then defined via odd extension (i.e. $f(x)=-f(-x)$ for $x\in[-\pi,0]$) for the other values of $x$ via $2\pi$-periodicity.